# Automated Emails with Ionic

Tags: email, ionic-framework

I have developed an ecommerce mobile application using Ionic Framework for Android. Now, my need of the hour is that whenever a customer makes a purchase and checkouts of the app, i need to send an automated email to the administrator about the order placed. All the tutorials and resources explain it how to send it with the aid of third party services like Gmail, where the customer has to explicitly select the service through which he wants to send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/email/) to automatically send emails.